# Mass range of a sub-brown dwarf

Tags: mass, nebula, brown-dwarf

Sub-brown dwarfs are celestial object that have planetary mass or are termed "[Planetary mass object/planemos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary-mass_object)". They do not lie in the range 13-80 MJ that defines "normal" brown dwarfs, which is the range from the boundary for deuterium fusion and the minimum mass of a star. So is there a lower mass limit for a sub-brown dwarf? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-brown_dwarf) has it being around 1 Jupiter mass however this is the mass of the nebula a sub brown dwarf can form from.

The maximum would probably be 13 MJ but what is the minimum? I think since the definition of a planemo is "a celestial object massive enough to achieve hydrostatic equilibrium", so it might be calculated using this.

**Difference between Planet and Sub-brown dwarf:**

Moreover Planemo's are kind of an grey area i.e superposition between a planet and an star

To clarify I am asking what is the lower mass limit for an object of low-mass that forms in isolation from a collapsing cloud and not in a Circumstellar disk where planets form (which is an further form of categorization to resolve  "where planemos are there  thus we can not conclude whether it is a star or an planet")?

Comment: Thanks a lot! @ProfRob .I mean a planemo not a planet. I think the difference  between a planet and a sub brown dwarf might be the IAU's 2nd rule which is that in order for an celestial planet to be considered an planet  it would have to be in orbit around a star, so even if it was orbiting a star it may be called an binary star system because brown dwarfs are made of Nebula and Planets are formed from protplanetary disks

Comment: I'm suggesting your question is hard to answer because nobody can even decide what is a brown dwarf and what is a planet. Is a gas giant ejected from its planetary system a brown dwarf? Because many are ejected.

Comment: But I think sub-brown dwarfs are not formed from "circumplanetary disk", Can you please share any citations so I can further investigate it?